# Replace text between two words

Tags: javascript, regex

This question seems to be simple and repetitive here in SO.

But consider this string: `SELECT a, b, c, d FROM`. I want to get **only** what is between `SELECT` and `FROM`.

Nice so I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110113/1267304) that propose this regex: `(?<=SELECT)(.*)(?=FROM)`. It's perfect if *lookbehind* works in JavaScript, according to [this post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript):

> Unlike lookaheads, JavaScript doesn't support regex lookbehind syntax

So it won't work(test it in [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) that is made for JS). [This anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5874783/1267304) proposes this regex: `SELECT=(.*?)FROM`. But it *includes* the two words, so it not fits my needs.

The purpose of this is to use in a `replace` function to transform this...

`SELECT a, b, c, d FROM`

into this...

`SELECT Count(*) FROM`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include the two words in your regex initially, and then replace it with something else that also includes the two words?

Comment: You can just replace the SELECT back... can't you not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Match all characters between two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: Why do you need to replace it? Just create a new string. No need to mess around with regular expressions.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at matching groups. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown:- Tried to implement what you wanted. Check my answer. I have also pasted the sample JSFiddle!!! :)

Comment: @DevlshOne just for your information, if you **read** the post you will see that I have mentioned that question and said that it not worked for me because is a *regex* only question, not specific for JavaScript, so that answers doesn't works for JavaScript. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a capturing group:

```
"SELECT a, b, c, d FROM".replace(/(SELECT)(.+?)(?= FROM)/, "$1 count(*)")
```

Comment: But is it really necessary to capture something you're certain what the contents are? I mean, you will _always_ capture `SELECT` and wouldn't it be faster and consume less memory to just put the literal `SELECT` in the replace string?

Comment: @Jerry: for this particular case it doesn't make a big difference, but generally I'd prefer captures over literals - just for DRY's sake.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
$("button").click(function() {
var srctext = $("#fixme").text();
console.log("old text: " + srctext);

var newtext = srctext.replace(/(SELECT)(.+?)(?= FROM)/, "$1 count(*)");
console.log("new text: " + newtext);

$("#fixme").text(newtext)
});
```

**WORKING JSFIDDLE:-** http://jsfiddle.net/tkP74/1597/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just put the `SELECT` back like I said in my comment:

```
str.replace(/SELECT (.*?)(?= FROM)/i, "SELECT Count(*)");
```

Comment: Huh, you don't even need a capture group here. Just doing `/SELECT .*?(?= FROM)/i` should work just as well, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZuq4/).

Comment: Yes, this makes totally sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to regular expressions for this specific string:

```
str = 'SELECT COUNT(*) ' + str.substr(str.indexOf('FROM'));
```

Comment: I like your approach.

Answer (score 1):

[Without regex](http://jsfiddle.net/zU3gq/1/):

```
var query = "SELECT a, b, c, d FROM";
var iSelect = query.indexOf("SELECT");
var selLen = "SELECT".length;
var iFrom = query.indexOf("FROM");
if (iSelect >= 0 && iFrom >= 0) {
    query = query.replace(query.substring(iSelect + selLen, iFrom), " COUNT(*) ");
    console.log(query);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I believe that regex was made to simplify code, anyway thank you.

Comment: This is great! just what i was looking for, using this logic I can also pull the contents of what is being replaced!