# How to extract a part of text from string

Tags: javascript

I have a str = `/posts/03faf64d3-4a838-9cf474ee66ed/show`

I would like to extract `03faf64d3-4a838-9cf474ee66ed` and and store it into a variable
how can I do that

Comment: Splitting by slashes may be wrong solution in some cases. See also this similar questions: [5642315](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315) or [5874670](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874670).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript's `split` function on the string. You can split your string by `/`.

```
const str = '/posts/03faf64d3-4a838-9cf474ee66ed/show';
const parts = str.split('/');
const id = parts[2]; // contains your uuid
```

More on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **split** property when it finds a **/**, causing it to separate the strings into different items and this becomes an array of strings, and thus select the item you are interested in:

```
var str = "/posts/03faf64d3-4a838-9cf474ee66ed/show";
var result = str.split("/")[2]
```